# if 3 of 5 images are clicked, jump to url

Tags: jquery, if-statement, fancybox, unbind

I have a row of 5 images. These images can be clicked. If a user clicks on an image, a video will open using the fancybox jquery. What I want is that the user can only open 3 videos (the user decides which ones). After the third video is played, I want jquery to send the user to another page. Also I want the image's opacity to change after it is clicked and to delete the URL of this clicked image, so the user can open this video only once.

What I have so far:

```
<a class="fancyboxIMG1" href="linktovideo1.swf">
<img src="BTN1.jpg" style="width:19%" id="BTN1">
</a>

<a class="fancyboxIMG2" href="linktovideo2.swf">
<img src="BTN2.jpg" style="width:19%" id="BTN2">
</a>

<a class="fancyboxIMG3" href="linktovideo3.swf">
<img src="BTN3.jpg" style="width:19%" id="BTN3">
</a>

<a class="fancyboxIMG4" href="linktovideo4.swf">
<img src="BTN4.jpg" style="width:19%" id="BTN4">
</a>

<a class="fancyboxIMG5" href="linktovideo5.swf">
<img src="BTN5.jpg" style="width:19%" id="BTN5">
</a>
```

the jquery code I'm using right now (I will copy the code for just one image, as I only need to change the image number to append it to the other four images):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    count = 5;

    $('#BTN1').click(function(){
        if (count >= 3){
        $(BTN1).css('opacity', '0.2');
        $('#BTN1').unbind('click');
        count--;
        $(".fancyboxIMG1").fancybox();
        }

        else {
        location.href='http://www.thelinktogoto.com';
    };
    });
</script>
```

I hope someone could help me out with this?!

Comment: did you init you var well ? I can see you have written `count = 5`not `var count = 5`

Comment: yeah i tried this already, but than it deletes the whole image after it's been clicked.

Comment: If the visitor reloads the page, then all (javascript) counters will be reset and then they can go on watching as many videos as they want. If that is critical to your implementation, you may rather need to handle it with (php) sessions and cookies.

Comment: Thanks, but that's why it jumps to another page after 3 images are clicked. It is made for kids, shown in a frame, which will be in fullscreen, so that won't be a problem. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a special class (e.g. `preview`) to each of the images which should be "clickable" and use the following script instead. With this you can add or remove videos/images easily:

```
$(".preview").on("click", function(ev) {
    var btn = $(this);

    // has this image already been clicked? Then it is "out of order"
    if (btn.data("clicked")) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    // mark as clicked
    btn.data("clicked", true);

    // show video in fancybox
    btn.closest("a").fancybox();

    // if 3 images have been clicked, redirect to url
    if ($('.preview[data-clicked="true"]').length == 3) {
        location.href='http://www.thelinktogoto.com';
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added the `.fancybox()` call

Comment: Uh, ok, still I don't get it. Do I keep the href before the image or do I need to delete this? Because if I keep it, it doesn't open the video in fancybox, if I delete it, it doesn't open anything at all...

Comment: Beside the new css class there should be no change to be made to your markup with this script.